# How will three persons (two males and one female) stand for congregational prayer?

Tags: jamaat

If three persons want to perform prayer like **father, son and mother** what would be the **standing position for jamaat** of three.

Comment: Father or son should lead prayer in front. Then the son/father should be behind and then mother should be behind them.

Comment: Your question is already answered in my answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/31162/13438

Answer (score 2):

In a congregation consisting of three people, two males and a female: The male imam will stand in front, the other male will stand to the right of the imam, and the female will stand behind the imam.

**Reference:**

> عن أنس بن مالك: أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم صلى به وبأمه، أو خالته، قال: فأقامني عن يمينه، وأقام المرأة خلفنا
>
> It was narrated from Anas bin Malik that the Messenger of Allah ﷺ led him and his mother, or maternal aunt in prayer. He said: "He made me stand on his right, and he made the woman stand behind us."
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:660b)</sup>

> ولو كان معه رجل وامرأة أقام الرجل عن يمينه والمرأة خلفه
>
> <sup>— [الموسوعة الفقهية , إمامة الصلاة (الإمامة الصغرى) , موقف الإمام](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/3693#p3)</sup>

Comment: But the questioner said that the woman in this case is the wife, so all three of them are mahram. Does the Hadith also apply to this case? may Allah have mercy on you

Comment: @Qataada I don't understand your concern. Anas was also a mahram to his mother\aunt. The relation between the imam and the woman is irrelevant, even then the Prophet was a mahram to Anas's mother\aunt Umm Sulaym and Umm Haraam.

Comment: Subhan Allah, I didn't know that the Noble Prophet (may peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) was a mahram with both Anas' mother and aunt. What's the daleel for this brother?

Comment: @Qataada  أم حرام أخت أم سليم أنهما كانتا خالتين لرسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم محرمين إما من الرضاع  وإما من النسب 
[[شرح مسلم](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1711/3503#p4)]

Comment: جزاك الله خيرا.