# How to line up a few followers in family congregational Salah?

Tags: salat, fiqh, jamaat

**How should a few family members line up in congregational Salah in following cases?**

1. A husband and a wife (or a son and a mother, or a brother and a sister, or a father and a daughter - a male and a female).
2. A father and a son (or two brothers - two males).
3. A husband and a wife and a son (or any other combination of two males and a female).
4. A husband and a wife and a daughter (or any other combination of a male and two females).
5. A husband and a wife and two sons (or any other combination of three males and a female).
6. A husband and a wife and a son and a daughter (or any other combination of two males and two females).

Comment: Some basic rules: If there are three or more males, then two of them will stand behind the Imam as usual. If there are two males, one will stand to the right of the Imam. A female always stands behind the male(s).

Comment: "A female always stands behind the male" Can an only female stand alone in the last row?

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/57077/20218

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. Jazakkallahu Hayrun :) Yet I am thinking about non Mahrams for the same cases. You can post an answer if that's ok:)

Comment: See also [Is it poassible to poray Jamat with just myself and my wife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24012/13438) and [How to can we offer fard prayer with just two people](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/how-can-we-offer-fard-namaz-with-just-two-people/29992#29992)

Comment: If an answer exists there's no reason why we should post another one it is better to close this post as a duplicate.