# Is Jamaat allowed in home?

Tags: salat, masjid, jamaat

In my extended family, there r many boys (brothers), they rather do a jamaat in house rather than go to a near mosque. Not joining them makes me feel bad but it also makes me feel bad if I don't go to a nearby mosque.

They have a certain reason of not going to the nearby mosque as the mosque doesn't do Salat-o-Salam and people tend to only offer fard so they think it is wahabi masjid

Comment: Your question has multiple answers on the site. See for example: [Is it possible to pray jamat with just myself and my wife](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24012/is-it-possible-to-pray-jamat-with-just-myself-and-my-wife) and [Will my salah be accepted if I pray at home](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30642/will-my-salah-be-accepted-if-i-pray-at-home?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: To the OP: Perhaps you can edit your question and add some more information. Is salaat-o-salam important to you? Can you do it by yourself in the mosque? Will your family members feel bad if you don't pray with them and instead pray in the mosque?

Comment: This [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/72398/they-pray-in-congregation-at-home) and this [fatwa](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Salah-Prayer/24626) may be relevant.

Comment: Be aware that neither the prophet nor his sahabah ever did Salat-o-Salam (What ever this might be). If one wants to do dhikr after prayer he should do it for himself in secret anything else has the doubt of being bid'ah. So the reason why they don't pray in that mosque is doubtful and could also be considered as sinful as Allah say: "Have you seen the one who forbids, A servant when he prays?  Have you seen if he is upon guidance. Or enjoins righteousness? Have you seen if he denies and turns away - Does he not know that Allah sees?" [96:9-14](https://legacy.quran.com/96/9-14)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Salat-o-Salam is a way of loudly collectively offering salutations to the Prophet (SAW). A certain group of people in the Indian subcontinent do it and a certain group of people in the Indian subcontinent oppose it.

Comment: And read also: "And who are more unjust than those who prevent the name of Allah from being mentioned in His mosques and strive toward their destruction. It is not for them to enter them except in fear. For them in this world is disgrace, and they will have in the Hereafter a great punishment." [2:114](https://legacy.quran.com/2/114) and [9:107](https://legacy.quran.com/9/107) and the surrounding verses.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely. Making Jamaath doesn't have any conditions in locations. Jamaath can be formed anywhere, if there's more than one person.